# How can access Button in Inner DataList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, datalist, asplinkbutton

Comments `DataList` (Outer) and Replies `DataList` (Inner).

While in Inner `DataList` there is a `LinkButton` that gets text from `TextBox`.

How I can access `Add` event of that `LinkButton`?

**.aspx code**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlComments" runat="server">
    <asp:DataList ID="dlReplies" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReply" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" CommandName="Add" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
    </asp:DataList>
</asp:DataList>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `OnItemCommand` to the nested DataList.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlReplies" runat="server" OnItemCommand="dlReplies_ItemCommand">
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void dlReplies_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //check for the correct commandname
    if (e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        //use findcontrol to find the textbox and cast it back to one
        TextBox tb = e.Item.FindControl("txtReply") as TextBox;

        Label1.Text = tb.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `commandName="click"` on you linkbutton.

```
 private void DataList1_ItemCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs e) {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
                    || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)) {
            DataList dtl2 = (DataList)(e.Item.FindControl("dlReplies"));
            dtl2.ItemCommand += new System.EventHandler(this.dtl2_ItemCommand);
        }
    }

    protected void dtl2_ItemCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs e) {
        if (e.CommandName == "click") {
            // 'do what you want here
        }
    }
```

Comment: It shows error red line under this `System.EventHandler(this.dtl2_ItemCommand)`